# open a pdf file programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on pdf. I am trying to open a pdf file from my application using the code below. But I failed to open.

```
private void openPdf() {

        File file = new File("mnt/sdcard.test.pdf");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(path);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No application found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

When I tried this code in emulator,it shows a toast saying "No application found"(bcoz,normally no pdf viewing application are installed in emulator). When I tested the same thing in device (specifically in funbook tab and in sony tab), it neither showed the Toast message nor it opened the pdf file. Can anybody point out the mistake in my code. Actually I am working with pdf for the first time. So my question is,

1. In device it didn't showed the toast message, which means there is a
   pdf viewing application installed in my phone? is it right?
2. If so, why the pdf is not opened using third party application.
3. If I want to list all pdf viewing applications installed in my
   phone to the user, what changes should I make in this code?

Answer (score 4):

I got solution of above problem, so try once;

Steps:-

1. create assets folder in src under your app name.
2. In this assets folder keep your pdf files  e.g. schedule1.pdf.
3. now come your activity i.e  MainActivity.java
4. setListener on any UI component what you want i.e (`Button`, `ImageView`, `ImageButton`);
5. In this listener call one user defined method i.e. `openPDFFiles()`

the openPDFFiles() method have below code:

```
private void openPDFFiles() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), “schedule1.pdf”);//here schedule1.pdf is the pdf file name which is keep in assets folder.
    try {
        in = assetManager.open(“schedule1.pdf”);
        out = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        copyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(“tag”, e.getMessage());
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(“file://” + getFilesDir() + “/schedule1.pdf”), “application/pdf”);

    startActivity(intent);
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

for `android 9 and 10` you should use this code

1-create one `class`

```
public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {

}
```

2-in `res` directory create one directory to name of `xml`
and create one file to name of `provider_paths.xml` and add this code

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

3-in `manifests` in `application` add this code

```
  <provider
    android:name=".Model.Utilitys.GenericFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
  </provider>
```

4-you should get Permission `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

5-and add this codes

```
String fileName="yourfile.pdf";

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/ir.tdaapp.paymanyar/files/File",fileName);

String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());

String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choseFile"));
```

6-I suggest you add this code to the `application` in `manifests`

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try LuxuryMode's method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8221594/1500067

I think your just missing the adobe package intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");

Comment: i avoided that piece code intentionly,bcoz i want open pdf file using all applcation,not just with adobe reader only

Comment: what do you mean by all applications? Do you want your app specifically to open up when you click on a pdf file?

Comment: to find whatever app is available to display PDFs

Comment: This method assumes the user has Adobe Reader installed. It's not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have nearly identical code that works fine, though I'm not opening a file from SD card in my app.

```
Activity mActivity = /* your activity */...;
String mFileName = /* path of my PDF file */...;

Uri uri  = Uri.fromFile(mActivity.getFileStreamPath(mFileName));

try
{
    Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intentUrl.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intentUrl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mActivity.startActivity(intentUrl);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "No PDF Viewer Installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

so your approach is right on.  Make sure you can open the file first ... i.e. use mActivity.openFileInput() to ensure you have a readable PDF.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using 3rd party library integration. Working libraries are listed below,
with SDK

> https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview
>   https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

with NDK

> https://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/detail?name=mupdf-1.2-source.zip&can=2&q=

guide to use 
@

> http://dixitpatel.com/integrating-pdf-in-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code here([Display PDF file inside my android application](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/02/15/display-pdf-file-inside-my-android-application/))

Add this dependency in your Gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="View PDF"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/tv_header"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPageChangeListener,OnLoadCompleteListener{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "android_tutorial.pdf";
    PDFView pdfView;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    String pdfFileName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pdfView= (PDFView)findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableSwipe(true)

                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }


    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe is too late for an answer, but your problem is cause by these 2 line:
`intent.setData(path);`
`intent.setType("application/pdf");`

When you setData and after that you setType, the second command will clean the path assingned in setData.
In this situation, you should use `setDataAndType(path,"application/pdf")`

> ```
> /**
>  * Set an explicit MIME data type.
>  *
>  * <p>This is used to create intents that only specify a type and not data,
>  * for example to indicate the type of data to return.
>  *
>  * <p>This method automatically clears any data that was
>  * previously set (for example by {@link #setData}).
>  *
>  * <p><em>Note: MIME type matching in the Android framework is
>  * case-sensitive, unlike formal RFC MIME types.  As a result,
>  * you should always write your MIME types with lower case letters,
>  * or use {@link #normalizeMimeType} or {@link #setTypeAndNormalize}
>  * to ensure that it is converted to lower case.</em>
>  *
>  * @param type The MIME type of the data being handled by this intent.
>  *
>  * @return Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls
>  * into a single statement.
>  *
>  * @see #getType
>  * @see #setTypeAndNormalize
>  * @see #setDataAndType
>  * @see #normalizeMimeType
>  */
> public Intent setType(String type) {
>     mData = null;
>     mType = type;
>     return this;
> }
> ```

[Javadoc Intent class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/135936072b24b090fb63940aea41b408d855a4f3/core/java/android/content/Intent.java)