# How to open PDF file in android device?

Tags: android

I am fresher to android. My task is to open a pdf file in android device. I searched a tutorials and tried it. But I could not open a pdf file. I dont know the error where I did?. Please help me anyone.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
        android:text="open" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pdftest;

import java.io.File;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File pdffile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/sdcard/abc.pdf");
        try
        {
            if(pdffile.exists())
            {
                Uri path=Uri.fromFile(pdffile);
                Intent objintent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                objintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                objintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(objintent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No viewer application Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pdftest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.pdftest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open a pdf file programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398239/open-a-pdf-file-programatically)

Comment: Can you post the error what you are getting ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the root from the second parameter in File class constructor. When you're instantiating File with File(String dirPath, String name) then the second parameter must contain just the file name and the first the directory where the file is located.

With this correction your code should work :

```
File pdffile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"abc.pdf");
```