# How to allow user to select only pdf file from internal and external memory in android

Tags: android, pdf, android-studio

As I am able to open the Downloads folder but PDF looks like disabled so I am not able to select PDF files. Is there  any other way to achieve this ?

Here is the code for Button Click

```
case R.id.pdf_Upload:
               Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("pdf/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), REQUESTCODE_PICK_Pdf);

            break; 

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {

    case REQUESTCODE_PICK_Pdf:
                if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_PICK_Pdf && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                        && null != data) {
                    Uri selectedPdf = data.getData();

                    PdfSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (selectedPdf.getLastPathSegment().endsWith("pdf")) {


                        System.out.println("Uri of selected pdf---->" + selectedPdf.toString());
                    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid file type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
    }
```

Permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221556/opening-pdf-file-programmatically-is-going-into-menu-page/8221594#8221594

Comment: do u have installed any pdf reader ?

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar I want to open storage where only PDF file will come and user can select the PDF file after that I can upload it . In my code Downloads folder--> opening --> Pdf files --> not selecting because looks like disabled

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar  Read the question carefully before discussing anything and commenting your useless opinions

Comment: @quicklearner. Read the question carefully before discussing anything and commenting your useless opinions

Answer (score 6):

this cod work for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the answer given by Omar, you can still add this to restrict the user's choice only for Internal and External documents with this simple line.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
```